# How to check if a namespaced function exists?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

Is there a way to find out if a function in a namespace exists? I'm trying to get the attribute value of an HTML element and then checking if the string value has a corresponding JavaScript function.

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://stackoverflow.com/" data-success-callback="$.Namespace.SomeFunction" />

var successCallback = $('#myLink').data('success-callback');
```

I know I can use **typeof window[callback] === 'function'** to check for functions declared globally but this doesn't seem to work with functions in a namespace; it's undefined.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Where `callback` is the `successCallback`?

Comment: FYI, it should be `.data('successCallback')`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: `typeof  myNamespace.myFunc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this instead:

```
function getProperty(objName) {
    var parts = objName.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, length = parts.length, obj = window; i < length; ++i) {
        obj = obj[parts[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Got it here: [Access namespaced javascript object by string name without using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981671/access-namespaced-javascript-object-by-string-name-without-using-eval)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming callback is your successCallback object doing window[callback] === 'function' will  only check that there is an object called **'$.Namespace.SomeFunction**' at the root of the window object. But what you want to achieve is to check if there is an object called SomeFunction in the object Namespace itself contained within the $ object.

To do so you can either use what @rps wrote aka typeof typeof myNamespace.myFunc if you already know the namespace and the function or use the below function that will traverse an object and look for a given path, in your case $.Namespace.SomeFunction :

```
var get = function (model, path, def) {
    path = path || '';
    model = model || {};
    def = typeof def === 'undefined' ? '' : def;
    var parts = path.split('.');
    if (parts.length > 1 && typeof model[parts[0]] === 'object') {
      return get(model[parts[0]], parts.splice(1).join('.'), def);
    } else {
      return model[parts[0]] || def;
    }
  }
```

and now do something like

```
typeof get(window, '$.Namespace.SomeFunction', 'undefined') === 'function'
```

Comment: Hi! How come it's only returning the jQuery namespace?